# How can i scroll the page with img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scroll the page vertically without using the scrollbar.
instead i want to use 2 image tags for scrolling the page.
this was the code i tried for the scroll but it didnt look good:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  div.mousescroll {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  div.mousescroll:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function left() {
      $(".wrapper2")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wrapper2").scroll(function right() {
      $(".wrapper1")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="first" class="wrapper1 ">

  <div id="first2" class=" div1  ">
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
<br />
<div id="second" class="wrapper2 mousescroll">
  <div id="second2" style=" overflow-x:scroll" class="div2">
    <table>

      ...............
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

imagine that the width of this table is 2000px and instead of scrollbar i wanna use two image tags that can do the scroll job.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you got any example code from where you've tried to approach this problem?

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  (function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
      slimScroll: function (o) {
        var ops = o;
        //do it for every element that matches selector
        this.each(function () {
          var isOverPanel,
            isOverBar,
            isDragg,
            queueHide,
            barHeight,
            divS = "<div></div>",
            minBarHeight = 30,
            wheelStep = 30,
            o = ops || {},
            cwidth = o.width || "auto",
            cheight = o.height || "250px",
            size = o.size || "7px",
            color = o.color || "#000",
            position = o.position || "right",
            opacity = o.opacity || 0.4,
            alwaysVisible = o.alwaysVisible === true;

          //used in event handlers and for better minification
          var me = $(this);

          //wrap content
          var wrapper = $(divS)
            .css({
              position: "relative",
              overflow: "hidden",
              width: cwidth,
              height: cheight,
            })
            .attr({ class: "slimScrollDiv" });

          //update style for the div
          me.css({
            overflow: "hidden",
            width: cwidth,
            height: cheight,
          });

          //create scrollbar rail
          var rail = $(divS).css({
            width: "15px",
            height: "100%",
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
          });

          //create scrollbar
          var bar = $(divS)
            .attr({
              class: "slimScrollBar ",
              style: "border-radius: " + size,
            })
            .css({
              background: color,
              width: size,
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              opacity: opacity,
              display: alwaysVisible ? "block" : "none",
              BorderRadius: size,
              MozBorderRadius: size,
              WebkitBorderRadius: size,
              zIndex: 99,
            });

          //set position
          var posCss = position == "right" ? { right: "1px" } : { left: "1px" };
          rail.css(posCss);
          bar.css(posCss);

          //wrap it
          me.wrap(wrapper);

          //append to parent div
          me.parent().append(bar);
          me.parent().append(rail);

          //make it draggable
          bar.draggable({
            axis: "y",
            containment: "parent",
            start: function () {
              isDragg = true;
            },
            stop: function () {
              isDragg = false;
              hideBar();
            },
            drag: function (e) {
              //scroll content
              scrollContent(0, $(this).position().top, false);
            },
          });

          //on rail over
          rail.hover(
            function () {
              showBar();
            },
            function () {
              hideBar();
            }
          );

          //on bar over
          bar.hover(
            function () {
              isOverBar = true;
            },
            function () {
              isOverBar = false;
            }
          );

          //show on parent mouseover
          me.hover(
            function () {
              isOverPanel = true;
              showBar();
              hideBar();
            },
            function () {
              isOverPanel = false;
              hideBar();
            }
          );

          var _onWheel = function (e) {
            //use mouse wheel only when mouse is over
            if (!isOverPanel) {
              return;
            }

            var e = e || window.event;

            var delta = 0;
            if (e.wheelDelta) {
              delta = -e.wheelDelta / 120;
            }
            if (e.detail) {
              delta = e.detail / 3;
            }

            //scroll content
            scrollContent(0, delta, true);

            //stop window scroll
            if (e.preventDefault) {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
          };

          var scrollContent = function (x, y, isWheel) {
            var delta = y;

            if (isWheel) {
              //move bar with mouse wheel
              delta = bar.position().top + y * wheelStep;

              //move bar, make sure it doesn't go out
              delta = Math.max(delta, 0);
              var maxTop = me.outerHeight() - bar.outerHeight();
              delta = Math.min(delta, maxTop);

              //scroll the scrollbar
              bar.css({ top: delta + "px" });
            }

            //calculate actual scroll amount
            percentScroll =
              parseInt(bar.position().top) /
              (me.outerHeight() - bar.outerHeight());
            delta = percentScroll * (me[0].scrollHeight - me.outerHeight());

            //scroll content
            me.scrollTop(delta);

            //ensure bar is visible
            showBar();
          };

          var attachWheel = function () {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
              this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", _onWheel, false);
              this.addEventListener("mousewheel", _onWheel, false);
            } else {
              document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", _onWheel);
            }
          };

          //attach scroll events
          attachWheel();

          var getBarHeight = function () {
            //calculate scrollbar height and make sure it is not too small
            barHeight = Math.max(
              (me.outerHeight() / me[0].scrollHeight) * me.outerHeight(),
              minBarHeight
            );
            bar.css({ height: barHeight + "px" });
          };

          //set up initial height
          getBarHeight();

          var showBar = function () {
            //recalculate bar height
            getBarHeight();
            clearTimeout(queueHide);

            //show only when required
            if (barHeight >= me.outerHeight()) {
              return;
            }
            bar.fadeIn("fast");
          };

          var hideBar = function () {
            //only hide when options allow it
            if (!alwaysVisible) {
              queueHide = setTimeout(function () {
                if (!isOverBar && !isDragg) {
                  bar.fadeOut("slow");
                }
              }, 1000);
            }
          };
        });

        //maintain chainability
        return this;
      },
    });

    jQuery.fn.extend({
      slimscroll: jQuery.fn.slimScroll,
    });
  })(jQuery);

  //invalid name call
  $("#Id").slimscroll({
    color: "#aaa",
    size: "6px",
    width: "392px",
    height: "525px",
  });
});
```